# Erro: string indices must be integers em loop

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

boa noite, estou precisando fazer um for para uma requisição baseado em um excel, com isso estou fazendo assim:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('D:/repositorio/python/leitura.xls')
count = 0
for y in df1['EAN']:   
        data ="{\"productCode\":\"EAN%d\"}" % (y)
```

Funciona corretamente, mas preciso usar outros campos do Excel Po, e estou tentando fazer assim:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('D:/repositorio/python/leitura.xls')
count = 0
for y in df1:   
        data ="{\"productCode\":\"EAN%d\"}" % (y['EAN'])
```

Só que assim esse erro está dando:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\OTACIO~1.BAR\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11848/1268633844.py in <module>
     19 for y in df1:
     20 
---> 21         data ="{\"productCode\":\"EAN%d\"}" % (y['EAN'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Poderiam me ajudar com a forma correta de fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar a função iterrows do dataframe do panda.

Faça algo como:

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
data ="{"productCode":"EAN%d"}" % (row['EAN'])